# Como instanciar um objeto de acordo com um evento do Front End?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos

Boa tarde, Pessoal.

Não sei se minha pergunta faz muito sentido, mas lá vai.

Por exemplo, eu tenho uma classe que tem diversas funções, e tenho o meu Index.php

Ai vamos lá, quando eu carrego o index e preciso executar um método de uma classe, como eu faço pra instanciar o objeto dessa classe e executar a função de acordo com uma ação do usuario? Por exemplo, quando o usuário clicar num botão ele vai instanciar o Objeto e executar determinada função.

Ex:

Classe:

```
<?php
 class usuario{

 private nome;

 public function getNome(){
  return $this->Nome;
 }
}
?>
```

Index:

...

```
$usuario = new usuario();
$usuario->getNome();
```

...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se eu entendi direito, você quer passar um valor de uma ação pra saber o que fazer depois. Normalmente se passa parâmetros por $_GET na url, $_POST via formulário ou quebrando a url quando se usa url amigável.

Passando uma ação através de um link a lógica é a seguinte:

Link:

```
<a href="index.php?acao=carregausuario">Carregar usuário</a>
```

Código php:

```
if(isset($_GET["acao"]))
{
    if($_GET["acao"]=="carregausuario")
    {
        $usuario = new usuario();
        $nome = $usuario->getNome();
    }
}
```

Depois é só dar um `echo $nome;` no lugar que tiver que exibir esse nome.

Comment: Perfeito, então ele só vai gerar o objeto se existir o POST/GET correto?

Comment: Sim. Nesse exemplo o objeto só será criado se existir o  get "acao" e se o valor desse get "acao" for igual a "carregausuario".

Answer (score 0):

Do HTML você não consegue executar um código PHP.
O que você pode fazer é utilizar o javascript para fazer uma requisição http para um script PHP que execute o que você quer.

Você pode fazer uma chamada como no código abaixo na ação que você queira.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST', // Ou GET
    url: 'arquivo-com-acao-desejada.php'
});
```

Comment: Isso não faria com que eu tivesse de já deixar os objetos instanciados? O que eu quero saber é como instanciar o Objeto de acordo com a ação do usuario.